# Multiple Twitter Bootstrap Popover on the same page only showing first content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a foreach loop loading posts on a page so I have a dynamic amount of post. Each post has a popover to display the users that liked the post.

Here's my problem:

Lets say user **A** and **B** like post **1**

User **C** and **D** like post **2**

When I click the popover for likes on post **2** I see users **A** and **B**. I should be seeing users **C** and **D**. Infact I see users **A** and **B** on every post on the page.

[I've made a fiddle to demonstrate this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrdy97e/). All pop overs are showing **Test 1**, this is incorrect. Only the first should be showing **Test 1**.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Pop-Over Test</h1>
  <a href="#" class="popover-test" id ="test1" rel="popover">Hover for popover</a>
    <div class="popover-list-content" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Test 1
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br>

    <a href="#" class="popover-test" id ="test2" rel="popover">Hover for popover</a>
    <div class="popover-list-content" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Test 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br>

    <a href="#" class="popover-test" id ="tes3" rel="popover" >Hover for popover</a>

</div>

$(function() {
    $('.popover-test').popover({
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            return $('.popover-list-content').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popover-list-title').html();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you might what to return $(this) instead of $('.popover-list-X') since it's just grabbing the first class.

Comment: Are you really using Bootstrap 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be more specific with your content selector. As it is, you're getting the first of an array of elements with class `popover-list-content`. You just want the one adjacent to the hovered link:

```
content: function () {
    return $(this).next('.popover-list-content').html();
},
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jmrdy97e/4/)**

Comment: Nice, I wasn't able to write up a fiddle. Thanks for getting that to him so quickly.